# Android: Broadcast Receiver not working despite being declared

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm trying to receive various intents to audit the usage activity on my phone. I'm using AndroidStudio, Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tomm.vpandroid2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".GlobalEventsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BROADCAST" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the GlobalReceiver:

```
package com.tomm.vpandroid2;
public class GlobalEventsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "viprol.receiver";

    public GlobalEventsReceiver() {
        Log.i(TAG, "global receiver constructed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "received action");
    }
}
```

The problem is the ctor and `onReceive()` methods never get called (even if I stick a breakpoint on them and debug).

I am using a OnePlusOne and have disabled PrivateGuard for this application. Not sure what else to try?

Comment: Try after removing <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />, is it work ?

Comment: Thanks you for that, that's what it was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will only match broadcasts for which the MIME type is `application/vnd.wap.mms-message`. Presumably, you want to pull this out, along with its associated action, in a separate `<intent-filter>` for the same `<receiver>`, though I haven't played with WAP much in recent years.

Second, I am not aware of there being a broadcast named `BROADCAST`, as in your first `<action>`.

Third, IIRC, you cannot list for `SCREEN_ON` from a manifest-registered receiver, but instead only from a receiver registered via `registerReceiver()`.